# Est-ce qu'on dit « travailler sur l'ordinateur » ou « travailler sur ordinateur » ?

Tags: usage, prépositions

Il y a plusieurs variantes de combiner le mot « travailler » avec le mot « ordinateur » :

- *travailler sur ordinateur*,
- *travailler sur l'ordinateur*, ainsi que
- *travailler à l'ordinateur*.

J'ai trouvé très peu sur Internet à ce sujet, sauf les discussions [yahoo answers](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080823004233AAvsaHB) et [wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2215604).

But : 
J'ai un slogan pour mon entreprise en français que j'ai traduit « Travaillez plus vite à l'ordinateur ! ». Je veux déterminer l'usage le plus commun pour la Suisse.  J'ai demandé plusieurs franco-suisses, mais il n'y a pas de consensus.

Qu'est-ce que les autorités recommandent ?

Comment: Question préliminaire, qui sont les autorités ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Autorités : Peut-être il y a un guide de style de langue pour le français qui sert comme référence pour le monde francophone. Cela existe pour l'allemand.

Comment: Celait pourrait être utile de savoir le slogan original.

Comment: Je propose des outils pour écrire plus vite. Travailler est utilisé dans le sense d'écrire. Est-ce qu'on dit aussi écrire sur ordinateur ?

Comment: Aucun des 3 ne me paraissent idiomatiques. Je dirais « travailler avec un ordinateur » ou à la rigueur « travailler sur un ordinateur ». Je suis français, pas suisse.

Comment: je vais rechercher sur un forum ou il y a aussi des Suisses. "travailler sur ordinateur" me parait okay.

Comment: Apparemment il n'y a aucun consensus, sur l'autre forum je n'ai reçu aucune réponse. Je prends la solution de cl-r et torr. Merci de votre aide !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Travaillez plus vite sur ordinateur » : lorsque votre activité est liée à l'ordinateur, alors vous travaillerez plus vite si vous suivez la publicité proposée.

Ici l'ordinateur est entendu comme substantif.

*Travailler à* indiquerait plutôt un lieu ou un établissement : travailler à la mairie, ou une activité : travailler à l'avancement d'un projet.

Comment: « Est entendu comme substantif » : je ne vois pas ce que ça pourrait être d'autre.

Answer (score 2):

Tout dépend du contexte, dans lequel travailler est utilisé.

Par exemple, il me semble plus naturel de dire « je vais travailler sur ordinateur » pour définir l'**ensemble des ordinateurs existants**. En revanche, il serait plus approprié de dire « je travaille plus vite sur l'ordinateur » s'il s'agit du mien !

Dans votre cas « Travaillez plus vite sur ordinateur » me parait clairement être le plus approprié.

Comment: « “ Travaillez plus vite à l'ordinateur ! ” est probablement correct, oui, mais pas en français » hein ?

Comment: @torr " est probablement correct, oui, mais pas en français " Ce n'est pas trop utile comme information, même si c'est amusant

Comment: « Travaillez plus vite à l'ordinateur ! » me semble correct dans le cas où l'on construirait un ordinateur. Mais ce n'est pas le sens recherché ici.

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais tendance à dire :
"Travailler plus vite avec votre ordinateur"

Comment: +1 Dans ce contexte, ça me semble plus correct. Travailler sur un ordinateur se dit aussi, mais c'est plus familier. NB: je suis Français tout comme Gilles, les Suisses voient peut-être les choses différemment.